# Debian 7 java Executable Flag Disappeared

Tags: linux, security, debian, 64-bit, java

I have an up to date Debian 7 server, also running Plesk 11. Yesterday exactly at the same time (2015-09-21 11:38:13 EET) the exec flag has been disappeared from all the `java` executables on the server. (I have several variants: one system-wide, several others packaged with Atlassian applications)

It seems to me either a goodwill crack or some update running and chmoding for some reason.

Did anyone had a similar issue? Are you aware of any update or malware dropping the exec flag from all the Java executables?

Java versions:

1. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

2. `/opt/atlassian/jira/jre/bin/java`

java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

3. `/opt/atlassian/confluence/jre/bin/java`

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Absolutely, now I'm looking for vulnerabilities of 3 java versions instead of just one.

Comment: Yep, the Debian one (1.7) is at least not vulnerable, but the other two of 1.8 are. Just replacing them all to a single one. Would you recommend using the http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu repository? (production server)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it; now that single java is being used only. I'll share if it turns out what has caused the loss of the exec flag.

Comment: Today it has disappeared again.. cannot be an accident

Comment: Instead of "infection" it could also be something *intentional* like the automatic java update. or a script that tries to "harden" the installation (by removing exec flags)